# AWS EC2 Reading an Offer File JSON file

Tags: c#, json, amazon-web-services, parsing

I am trying to parse the AWS EC2 Reading an Offer File JSON file and I have a problem reading it. As you can see in the JSON file, there is a list of products and the key value of the JSON file is different each time and I cannot read it.
Any ideas how to read the file?

```
"Reserved" : {
  "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF" : {
    "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ" : {
      "offerTermCode" : "HU7G6KETJZ",
      "sku" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF",
      "effectiveDate" : "2017-02-28T23:59:59Z",
      "priceDimensions" : {
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U",
          "description" : "Upfront Fee",
          "unit" : "Quantity",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "11213"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        },
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7",
          "description" : "Windows (Amazon VPC), hs1.8xlarge instance-hours used this month",
          "beginRange" : "0",
          "endRange" : "Inf",
          "unit" : "Hrs",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "1.2510000000"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        }
      },
      "termAttributes" : {
        "LeaseContractLength" : "1yr",
        "OfferingClass" : "standard",
        "PurchaseOption" : "Partial Upfront"
      }
    },
    "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.38NPMPTW36" : {
      "offerTermCode" : "38NPMPTW36",
      "sku" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF",
      "effectiveDate" : "2015-04-30T23:59:59Z",
      "priceDimensions" : {
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.38NPMPTW36.2TG2D8R56U" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.38NPMPTW36.2TG2D8R56U",
          "description" : "Upfront Fee",
          "unit" : "Quantity",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "16924"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        },
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.38NPMPTW36.6YS6EN2CT7" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.38NPMPTW36.6YS6EN2CT7",
          "description" : "Windows (Amazon VPC), hs1.8xlarge instance-hours used this month",
          "beginRange" : "0",
          "endRange" : "Inf",
          "unit" : "Hrs",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "1.0910000000"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        }
      },
      "termAttributes" : {
        "LeaseContractLength" : "3yr",
        "OfferingClass" : "standard",
        "PurchaseOption" : "Partial Upfront"
      }
    },
    "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.NQ3QZPMQV9" : {
      "offerTermCode" : "NQ3QZPMQV9",
      "sku" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF",
      "effectiveDate" : "2015-04-30T23:59:59Z",
      "priceDimensions" : {
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.NQ3QZPMQV9.6YS6EN2CT7" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.NQ3QZPMQV9.6YS6EN2CT7",
          "description" : "USD 0.0 per Windows (Amazon VPC), hs1.8xlarge instance-hour (or partial hour)",
          "beginRange" : "0",
          "endRange" : "Inf",
          "unit" : "Hrs",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "0.0000000000"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        },
        "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.NQ3QZPMQV9.2TG2D8R56U" : {
          "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.NQ3QZPMQV9.2TG2D8R56U",
          "description" : "Upfront Fee",
          "unit" : "Quantity",
          "pricePerUnit" : {
            "USD" : "42860"
          },
          "appliesTo" : [ ]
        }
      },
      "termAttributes" : {
        "LeaseContractLength" : "3yr",
        "OfferingClass" : "standard",
        "PurchaseOption" : "All Upfront"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Dictionary<string, ...>` whenever encounter variable keys with well-structured values:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach (var offer in obj.Reserved.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Values))
{
    Console.WriteLine(offer.effectiveDate);
    foreach (var priceDim in offer.priceDimensions.Values)
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + priceDim.description);
}

// .....................

public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Offer>> Reserved { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
    public string offerTermCode { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public DateTime effectiveDate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, PriceDimension> priceDimensions { get; set; }
    public TermAttributes termAttributes { get; set; }
}

public class PriceDimension
{
    public string rateCode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string beginRange { get; set; }
    public string endRange { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> pricePerUnit { get; set; }
    public object[] appliesTo { get; set; }
}

public class TermAttributes
{
    public string LeaseContractLength { get; set; }
    public string OfferingClass { get; set; }
    public string PurchaseOption { get; set; }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nj7lz2

N.B. I'm assuming you process the JSON in C# using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).